# Custom agent image with Kubernetes Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I have been using csanchez's kubernetes-jenkins plugin to run my slave.  Everything works, but now I need a custom agent image.  I have changed the settings for the plugin from the default agent image to mine (in Container Template->Docker image), but when I check the logs in k8s I can see that it is still using the default.

Is this the right place to change it?  Is this a bug?

When I manually add a container based on my image named "jnlp" in the Jenkinsfile it works as expected.  It only uses the default image when I try to change things through the GUI.

I also tried adding a new cloud entry with the correct settings, but that one also does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

After doing a lot of research, I discovered the root cause.  I'm adding this to help any future searchers.

The issue is that the plugin won't use your pod template if you're using YAML to define your containers.  If you do not have a container named "jnlp", it silently injects one using the stock image.  It does not matter what you put in the container template in the GUI config.

If you define your pod with yaml, and you want a custom jnlp image, then you must also include that container definition in your spec and it must be named "jnlp".

As an alternative, you can just use the pipeline syntax and not yaml.  In this case, it will inherit from the template.  Note that this only works in specific cases:
a) You can use the scripted pipeline.  I haven't tested this, but according to my research this will work without restrictions.
b) You can use the declarative pipeline, but only if you have one container (not counting jnlp).  If you want to use the declarative pipeline with multiple containers, then you must use yaml.

Comment: Hero. This was it exactly... Things may have changed since your initial answer, as now I see this message conveniently hidden by the question mark next to container name when you go to add a second container "The name for the container to be run. One container is automatically created with name jnlp, and runs the Jenkins JNLP agent service. In order to replace the default JNLP agent, the name of the container with the custom JNLP image must be jnlp.
" ... Talk about obfuscation..!  Literal days debugging this :-/